# Как накатить новую версию телеграм бота, не выключая старую?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram, deploy

Никак не могу найти информацию о том, как сделать deploy новой версии своего бота, при этом не выключая старую. Например, есть рабочий бот, который уже запущен на сервере и у него есть уже большое кол-во пользователей. И вдруг потребовалось добавить какую то кнопку или расширить функционал. При этом выключать бота не вариант - как быть?

Comment: При этом еще нужно потестировать новый функционал или он уже оттестирован и вопрос в том, чтобы добавить его? Бот использует вебхуки сервера?

Comment: Уже протестирован новый функционал и нужно просто его добавить в уже работающий бот. Бот не использует вебхуки, только полинг

Comment: Перезагружать вам, думаю, придется в любом случае - бот работает на питоне, код на питоне и уже в памяти интерпретатора, поэтому понадобится перезапустить интерпретатор, т.е. бота. Во-первых, это можно сделать ночью, когда количество юзеров минимально. Во-вторых, вы запускали 2 бота с один и тем же токеном? Это мое предположение, но вероятно, если запустить новую версию бота, пока работает старая, будут ругательства, что один токен используется, но когда старый бот будет убит, то новый без проблем продолжит работу

Comment: Общее впечатление - что запуск новой версии без перезагрузки старой создаёт больше проблем, чем решает. Бот - довольно примитивная штука, которую можно представить как вполне транзакцинную систему относительно сообщений. Возможно даже - с сохранением состояния во внешнем хранилище. Он может "умирать" между двумя сообщениями и никто этого не заметит. Мой аргумент: пользователи на заметят, что бот выключился, до тех пор, пока не пошлют ему сообщение. Если быстро выключить и включить - вообще никто ничего не заметит

Comment: На одном форуме предлагают blue-green deploy. Изучив эту технологию - понял ее механизм, но вот реализацию так и не понял.
На счет того, что нужно поймать момент, когда нет обращений к боту, и вырубить старую версию кода и включить новую - это понятно, но как технически поймать этот момент и выполнить замену?

Comment: Думаю, переход на вебхуки позволит решить множество проблем, в том числе проблему обновления